# Extract a sub djvu file of multiple pages

Tags: djvu

I have a djvu file of multiple pages. How can I extract a new djvu file that consists of only a subset of multiple pages?

For example, a djvu file has 10 pages, and I would like to extract a new djvu file consisting of pages 3-6 of the original djvu file. Can it be done with some commands of djvulibre, such as djvused, djvm, ...? I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Consider two different cases: extract with and without removal of pages from the original djvu file.

Answer (score 8):

Get DjView4 from [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/), File -> Save as... there you can select pages to save.

djview is also available as Ubuntu package by default on the sysem.